# Como receber o view model num GET request WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Boas, eu tenho aqui um problema com a minha API e gostaria de pedir a vossa ajuda. Tenho aqui um formulário em Knockout JS, faço serialize de um constructor que por sua vez me devolve uma querystring assim

> API?Page=1&MinPrice=185&MaxPrice=694

O meu problema é  que a API não entende o que é isto e devolve me isto

```
{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nGet on type SiteMvc.Controllers.ProductAPIController\r\nGet on type SiteMvc.Controllers.ProductAPIController","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":"   em System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   em System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   em System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

ListVM

```
public class ListVM 
{

    public decimal? MinPrice { get; set; }

    public decimal? MaxPrice { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

    public int ProductType { get; set; }

}
```

API Controller

```
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(int page, [FromUri]ListVM vm)
            {

                CompanyManager m = new CompanyManager();
                HttpResponseMessage r = CheckEntryJson(m);
                if (r != null)
                    return r;

                ProductsBL bl = new ProductsBL(m.CompanyID);

                var query = bl.GetProducts();

                if (vm.MinPrice.HasValue)
                    query = query.Where(x => x.ProductStore.Price >= vm.MinPrice);
                if (vm.MaxPrice.HasValue)
                    query = query.Where(x => x.ProductStore.Price <= vm.MaxPrice);

                if (vm.CategoryID.HasValue)
                    query = query.Where(x => x.CategoryID == vm.CategoryID);




                Func<ProductType, string> getProductTypeName = x => x.ToName();

                var result = query.Select(x => new ProductAPIModel
                {

                    Name = x.Name,
                    TotalPrice = x.ProductStore == null ? 0 : x.ProductStore.TotalPrice,
                    ID = x.ProductID,
                    ProductType = getProductTypeName(x.ProductType),
                    Reference = x.Reference,
                    Description = x.Description

                });
     if (result == null) return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

                var json = new
                {
                    Items = result.Skip(pageSize * (page - 1)).Take(pageSize).ToList(),
                    TotalItems = result.Count()
                };

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
            }


        }
```

O meu objectivo é fazer com que a API perceba que isto são campos do model sem ter que recorrer a pôr os campos todos à mão como parâmetros e/ou mexer nas routes

Obrigado desde já !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para quem tiver dúvidas, para resolver este problema, decidi abandonar o RESTful da API e especificar actions dentro das mesmas, utilizo gets, no entanto no razor especifico na `Url.Route` a `action` e assim o mvc já consegue decifrar a query string e comparar a mesma com o model

Routes

> ```
>       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
>         name: "DefaultApi",
>         routeTemplate: "api/{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
>         defaults: new { action = "Default", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
>         constraints: new { company = @"\d+" } //Obriga a que o company seja um valor númerico
>         );
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Caso esteja usando API 2+, voce deveria usar anotações nas suas actions. Fica mais elegante e mais simples de configurar.

```
[RoutePrefix("/api/product")]
public class ProductApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet] // Sempre é bom ser explícito
    [Route("{page}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] int page, [FromUri] ListVM vm) {...}
}
```